# How to generate/bundle typescript definitions from .d.ts of dependecies in node_modules

Tags: typescript

I'm building sdk and I want to include types from my internal modules into bundled /dist/*.d.ts file.

I want to hide this internal module in bundled result.

This is my current result of tsc compilation

```js
// index.ts
import { TestType } from '@internal-types/module1/TestType'

export const testFunction = (param: TestType) => {
 // ...
}
```

```js
// dist/index.d.ts
import { TestType } from '@internal-types/module1/TestType'
export declare const testFunction: (param: TestType) => number;
```

but I want to something like

```js
declare interface TestType {
  testProp: string
}
export declare const testFunction: (param: TestType) => number;
```

`'@internal-types/module1'` already contains `TestType.d.ts` file

I've tried to copy imported modules before tsc compilation and change import path but problem was when some type use/import another type inside internal module.

Is it possible to configure typescript to include ts definitions inside node_modules to bundle/generate them instead of just reference them?